# COM Error when attempting to set Search Settings XML via CSOM

Tags: search, csom, 2016, search-schema

When trying to set the search settings via CSOM in SP2016 I received the following Error:

> retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid {0ff1ce16-0005-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 800703fa illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Searching brought me to this question [Failed to retrieve the COM class factory for component with CLSID SP.SPRequest](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/failed-to-retrieve-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-sp-sprequest).

The property "Load User Profile" was also set to false in the DEV environment where the same Code and Search Schema XML were running without issue.

Doing `iisrest /noforce` on all Servers fixed the issue.